# What is this blue insect?

Tags: entomology

I found this insect in my garden

[image]

It's the first time I see this insect, so I'm wondering what it is.

It has blueish, purplish reflections, a head like an ant or wasp but it's the size of a thumb (4-5cm)

I am located in Hungary if it can help identify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that this is an [oil beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meloe_violaceus) (also known as blister beetle) of the family Meloidae. In this special case this is probably the [violet oil beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meloe_violaceus) (*Meloe violaceus*), although this does not completely coincide with the size you mention. The slightly different color is probably caused by the different lighting.

See the image from this Wikipedia for comparision:

[image]

Be careful with them, as they can secrete a poisonous substance making blisters on the skin (hence there name) when they feel attacked. For more information see also [here](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/urban/medical/blister_beetles.htm).

Comment: That's definitely the same as the picture just a big one. http://bugoftheweek.com/blog/2013/1/7/look-but-do-not-touch-blister-beetles-epicuata-and-meloe-spp